# RESTful Services Upload Boundaries SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-services, batch

What are the limitations/boundaries for the SharePoint RESTful services end points for document upload in SharePoint 2013?

i.e. how many files can be uploaded via the RESTful service end point per second?  what file size limitations are in place for the RESTful service?

I am asking in the scenario of batch processing many thousands of documents into SharePoint via web services in both an on-premise scenario and a cloud (O365) scenario.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn903506.aspx

Comment: There is no limits with the number of file per second or minute, the call is asynchronous.
The max file size per upload is 2Gb using Full Rest Api.(JSOM is 1,5Mb)

Comment: @Marco do you have some validation or examples / case study / documentation that I could reference to prove this?

Comment: mmmm, the last time that I post a blocg link the moderator get fussy. Check this link: [Uploading files with FULL REST API](https://garabound.wordpress.com/2015/09/23/subiendo-archivos-con-metadata-con-full-rest-api/)

Answer (score 3):

I can't point you to MSDN or TechNet reference but a colleague has informed me there is a limit of 15 requests that can can execute in a REST batch request, and 30 for CSOM.  If I can locate "official" references I will update this answer.

Batch support in REST is not available for on-prem 2013, it was added for the 2016 release.

And for upload limit on-prem, it has to be configured to support 2GB.  By default it's 50 MB.

Comment: So 15 uploads per batch request? It sounds very low. How many uploads would this equate to per second? Is it 1 batch request per second which asynchronously uploads 15 documents?

Comment: I don't know of a published bandwidth threshold, they are different based on interface and service for O365 (but there are limits).  It's also dependent on your own infrastructure, where you upload from and where the tenant is located.  I guess the short answer is you have to test it.