# What is the Max File Size which can be uploaded to document Library through Rest API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am assigned with the requirement to upload multiple documents to the SharePoint online document library through rest API

I have seen in the MSDN documentation that max limit is **2GB**

I want to know whether **2GB** limit is per each request or single file size should be with in the **2GB**

any help in this regards would be helpful

Comment: Have you checked this one ? https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest and this one too :) https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160223/restful-services-upload-boundaries-sharepoint